# No any sources are loaded in struts2 to the browser

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

In Struts2 application, any other source(images, css, javascript files) cannot be retrieved to the browser.

For example, I add  `<img src="myimage.jpg" />` in JSP page,but image is not viewed in the browser. The JSP page and the image exist in `web` folder, not in `WEB-INF` I am sure that the image exists in the given path(I use Netbeans IDE and it gives the path automatically,too), I checked the image manually in the relevant location,it is ok.

I m not sure whether it is a problem with Struts (I don't believe so),but I created another normal Java EE project which has only JSP pages no struts framework included, then everything worked fine(images,css,js called).  Please any one let me know where my fault is in? Thanks in advance.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>/account.jsp</url-pattern>
            <include-prelude>/header/header.jsp</include-prelude>
        </jsp-property-group>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <display-name>TopBanner</display-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <include-prelude>/header.jsp</include-prelude>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
        <servlet-name>ItemAction</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ItemAction</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping-->
</web-app>
```

Comment: This isn't enough info to help; we know nothing about your app's configuration, deployment etc. You're right that it's not a Struts issue, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton, Thanks, I created more apps with struts2 framework in NetBeans IDE. They work fine.(but first times,they also failed.I rebuild again and again.then they ran fine). Still I can't understand whether problem is. I put the web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that the browser doesn't know that your request is handled by a servlet, then by a JSP. When it resolves relative paths, it doesn't resolve them using the path of the JSP as the base path, but by using the path of the invoked URL.

For example, if the browser address bar contains the following address:

```
http://localhost/app/foo/bar/baz.action
```

and the generated HTML contains

```
<img src="myimage.jpg"/>
```

the browser will look for the image in

```
http://localhost/app/foo/bar/myimage.jpg
```

even if the JSP generating the HTML is in the root of the webapp (i.e. at the URL `http://localhost/app/theJsp.jsp`)

I recommend always using absolute paths for images, JS files and other resources:

```
<img src="<c:url value='/myimage.jpg'/>"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just directly try a normal JSP (not through  an action) and no any action called. URL is `http://localhost:8084/OnlineBooking/index.jsp` . Also then I tried with JSTL as you mentioned. but still images are not displayed. When I print the URL in the page, it was `/OnlineBooking` .

Answer (score 1):

If your `images` directory or folder resides in your `web` directory. do this

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/myimage.jpg" />
```

this solves it

Comment: Thanks. I tried as you said. but it didn't work yet. Here was the URL for the `img` in the browser `src="/OnlineBooking/images/hill.jpg"` the image hill.jpg exists in the folder images and images folder is in folder web` .

Comment: @AashMaharoon is `OnlineBooking` your context path? Check your deployment directory if hill.jpg actually exist in `images` folder.